How to get a uniform backdrop blur effect?
When applying a backdrop-filter blur the result differs in uniformity between different browsers:

From left to right: Safari, Chrome, Firefox
With respect to uniformity, Safari is doing best, followed by Chrome and Firefox. I am not sure why there are such stark difference between browsers, but I would like to get a more uniform effect as Safari delivers but in all browsers.
My use case is this: I am using a blurred header and when scrolling over e.g. text, the non-uniform effect, especially in Firefox, leads to a flashing of the header at the edges which looks strange.
Here is the code used to generate the images (adding a border):


.box {
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.blur {
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  position: absolute;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="blur">
</div>




give a border to .blur then set it also top:0;left:0;  To better see where it actually stands ;)

@G-Cyrillus I have added a border in the example and set explicit left and top. But I am facing the same problem. Was your tip supposed to solve it?

from  my FF and your snippets, top left resets the blur box to the top left corner ans shows a similar result to chrome/safari. Border is to see where it stands and  if each browser put that element at different position. if position are the same, firefox probably need an extra negative margin equal to the blur() value to fully cover the area beneath.

@G-Cyrillus Thanks for your suggestion. But so far as I understand it that won't work. Adding margins changes the rendering so that the red box appears more inside the blurred area. That is not what I am after. Also, with respect to the use case I mention, adding negative margins seems to be a non-starter.

Thinking about the negative margin suggestion by @G-Cyrillus made me come up with a possible solution using a wrapper. I wouldn't call it perfect (because it shows blur from elements close by) but maybe it's as good as it gets?


.box {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.outer {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.blur {
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="blur">
  </div>
</div>



